# How to customise 3D scatter plot

Tags: r, scatter-plot, scatter3d

Let say, I have below `3D scatter plot`

```
library(mvtnorm)
library(threejs)
u <- seq(-5, 5, by = .1)
v <- seq(-5, 5, by = .1)
M <- expand.grid(u,v)

x <- M$Var1
y <- M$Var2
sigma <- matrix(c(1, .5, .5, 1), nrow = 2, byrow = TRUE)
z <- dmvnorm(x = M, sigma = sigma)

scatterplot3js(x, y, z, phi = 40, theta = 20,
          color=rainbow(length(z)),
          colkey = FALSE,
          cex = .3,
          main = "Bivariate Normal")
```

While this plot is okay, I want to change the labels `x`, `y`, and `z` with some custom names i.e. `A 1`, `B 1`, `C 1`.

Also, instead of displaying the tick marks of `z` axis as row, I was to add `%` e.g. instead of just reporting `0.18`, I want to report `0.18%`

Is there any way to achieve these.

Thanks for any pointer.

Answer (score 1):

`axisLabels` and `z.ticklabs` are these arguments what you are looking for? see `?scatterplot3js`

```
scatterplot3js(x, y, z, phi = 40, theta = 20,
               color=rainbow(length(z)),
               colkey = FALSE,
               cex = .3,
               main = "Bivariate Normal",
               axisLabels=c("Axis label 1", "Axis label 2 [%]", "Axis label 3"),
               z.ticklabs = c("0.00%","0.04%", "0.07%", "0.11%", "0.15%", "0.18%"))
```

[image]

Comment: Many thanks for this. However I see that you have put the z-axis labels manually i.e. `c("0.00%","0.04%", "0.07%", "0.11%", "0.15%", "0.18%"`. How did you get those original values i.e. `0.00, 0.04. 0.07` etc? Is there any alternate way other than such manual insertion?

Comment: I could not see an obvious way to provide labels for the z-axis breaks programmatically, in the way you can for say `ggplot`. I am not really familiar with `threejs`, looking at the question was an opportunity for me to have a look at a (for me) new 3D plotting package.